# How to make access to all UI Control in first load?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I Used Modern UI for WPF and use this library.

From menu link group I used this :

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="SKBPK2014.MainWindow"

    ContentSource="/UI/Pages/Home.xaml">

   <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Sampel">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="HOME" Source="/UI/Pages/Home.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="DAFTAR SAMPEL" Source="/UI/Kuesioner/DaftarSampel.xaml" />
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
```

How to get All UI control in a list in the first load. Not clicking the `mui:Link`. ? I wanna get like this

```
List<UIControl> UiControl;
```

it will contains all UIControl in My `ModernWindow`. so it will contains `{Home,DaftarSampel,}` object List in the first load..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an IoC container like Unity or Autofac? You could register all of your control classes as singleton instances in the container, and then you could get references to them from the container on first load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what is your final goal, but I will give you a hint. You can get the visual (or logical) items in you window tree, that match some condition you want. For that propose you can use this methods:

**For the visual items:**

```
        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisualChild(DependencyObject item, Func<DependencyObject, bool> condition)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            var q = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item); i++)
            {
                var t = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i);
                if (condition(t))
                    yield return t;
                q.Enqueue(t);
            }

            while (q.Count > 0)
            {
                var subchild = q.Dequeue();
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(subchild); i++)
                {
                    var t = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(subchild, i);
                    if (condition(t))
                        yield return t;
                    q.Enqueue(t);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**For the Logical Items**

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetLogicalChild(DependencyObject item, Func<DependencyObject, bool> condition)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var q = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        foreach (var w in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(item))
        {
            var t = w as DependencyObject;
            if (condition(t))
                yield return t;
            q.Enqueue(t);
        }

        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            var subchild = q.Dequeue();
            foreach (var w in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(subchild))
            {
                var t = w as DependencyObject;
                if (condition(t))
                    yield return t;
                q.Enqueue(t);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If you want to control the logic, you should to implement the Mvvm pattern. Hope my tips helps...